# Spring annotations @NotNull and @Size do not work

Tags: spring-mvc

I've created a simple page project, which checks a single inputdata field "name" and if it's empty or size is less than 5, it has to show a error-message.

At the moment BindingResult thinks there is no error all the time.

Spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Student class:

```
package com.mvc;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    public class Student {

        @NotNull(message = "IsRequired!")
        @Size(min = 5, message = "must be greater than 5!")
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
package com.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
            BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
        } else {
            return "student-confirm";
        }
    }



}
```

If required, i can post web.xml, and jsp pages.

Comment: Make sure you have hibernate validator jar in your project.

Comment: Maven includes:
hibernate-validator 5.2.4.Final, hibernate-validator-annotation-processor 6.0.2.Final, hibernate-validator-cdi 6.0.15.Final, validation-api 2.0.1.Fina

Comment: you need the same versions of  hibernate-validator and hibernate-validator-annotation-processor; remove explicit declaration of hibernate-validator-cdi

Comment: I've updated those dependencies in maven, now it's: hibernate-validator 6.0.13.Final,  hibernate-validator-annotation-processor 6.0.13.Final; I deleted hibernate-validator-cdi.  Unfortunatly, NotNull, Size dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Removed previous version of Tomcat(7.0) and installed latest version.